# How to determine the source of a job submission

Tags: cron, documentation, submission, hpcc-ecl

I am searching for a way to determine how a job was initiated on the HPCC cluster.
There are several ways to submit a job. For example:
1- a manual submission via the ECL IDE / ECL Watch
2- an external cron submission
3- an ECL submission of dynamically built code
4- if a file lands in a directory, it triggers a submission
etc.
I can retrieve some important information by executing a STD.System.Workunit.WorkunitList,
but I cannot find any function that would give me an attribute indicating the source of
that submission.

HPCC is a data-centric platform and ECL reflects that approach. So I am attempting to build
a matrix that defines the code in relation to that data. A product is technically a bunch
of data (files) that is the result of source input -> scrub and transformation processes -> to
the final base files. Then those files are then prepped / indexed for external use:
1- Roxie queries
2- PowerBI
3- webpage
4- reports ftp'd or emailed
etc.

I want to build this matrix that defines (by product) the initiating job(s), where they were initiated, any schedule (?), the associated input/output files (flagging whether they are source/intermediate/base/output). I am trying to design this so that the matrix can be dynamically built, because as we all know:
(1) nowhere does this type of documentation exist so that if someone new comes in to work on
a product, they can go and see the scope and life cycle of the data,
(2) nobody likes to document,
(3) the second any manual documentation is actually created and saved; it is out of sync with reality

So far, the design will be a collection of files (defined by the level of detail) which would
then be JOINed together to yield the final matrix. Not sure if this would end up as a PowerBI report or a webpage...still tossing that around. Still, this might prove to be something useful for
anyone using HPCC who wants a 30,000 ft view of their product.

I have attempted to programmatically scan a WUID output, looking for the necessary attributes but I have had little success.

I appreciate any assistance / comments.

Comment: To ensure your questions are seen by the HPCC Systems/ECL team, you should always use the HPCC-ECL tag in your post, otherwise they could be missed. -- Richard

Answer (score 1):

No matter what component submits ECL to execute on the platform, they all ultimately end up going through the same WsWorkunits API, which is the public SOAP / REST interface.

While some client applications will leave a fingerprint so you can deduce where it came from, it is not a foolproof mechanism...

For Example:  In http://play.hpccsystems.com:8010/esp/files/index.html#/workunits/W20221115-075604/xml you can see the ECL IDE appends some meta information into the Workunit (it stores the IDE version number in the "Application" section)

Comment: Thank you for that excellent example! I have known jobs with the various ways they were initiated, so I'll try looking in that "Application" section to see if I can detect any patterns can use.

Comment: I can see the various attributes in the XML, but I have to examine each one manually. If I have a list of WUIDs, is there a service that would allow me to retrieve the XML metadata so I can parse out the necessary data? I haven't seen any service in the documentation except perhaps a SOAPCALL, but that looks like it wouldn't work. Say I have a single WUID, I would need the IP address for the Dali/Sasha where the executed WUID resides, then access just the XML metadata. Then I can parse the results. Unfortunately, I would have to do this for hundreds of WUIDs to accomplish building my matrix.